# Why does REDMI NOTE 11 user are not seeing text on my app?

Tags: android, redmi-device

I have an app on play store, but about 2 months some users are not been able to see any text on the app.

I use de default font for everything.

here's the config on the theme file

```
    <style name="RobotoTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
    </style>
```

any suggestions why this is happening?

I used to use the light Roboto font, and tried to change to the regular one, but still doesn't work